# passing element / identifier reference to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I'm building my almost first JavaScript App. I'm trying to get multiple spinners as such: 
  + [0] - 
  + [3] - 
  + [0] -

I have the following code for adding and subtracting spinner values:

```
$('#plus').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var value = $('#number').val();
    value++;
    $('#number').val(value);
});
$('#minus').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var value = $('#number').val();
    if (value > 0) value--;
    $('#number').val(value);
});
```

and the following markup for the spinners:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <p><button id="plus" data-inline="true">    +</button>
    <input type="text" id="number" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
    <button id="minus" data-inline="true">-</button></p>
</div>
```

However I don't understand how to pass the identifier of a  spinner to the add/subtract function, i.e. I don't want to write multiple add/subtract functions, one for each spinner.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$('.plus').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var numberControl = $(this).parent().find('.number'), value = numberControl.val();
    value++;
    numberControl.val(value);
});
$('.minus').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var numberControl = $(this).parent().find('.number'), value = numberControl.val();
    if (value > 0) value--;
    numberControl.val(value);
});
```

JsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8C8c8/4/

What this does is:

- for the currently clicked button ( `this` in our case), go to the `parent()` and `find()` the child that is of type `input`
- use the found element to get/set the `val`

I advise you to use `class` instead of `id` if your element is going to exist more than 1 times. `id` is used if the element exists only 1 time in your HTML. If it will exists multiple times then you should use a `class`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry to be a little thick on this, but I still don't see what I should pass to the function. Should I make all the spinner elements class="minusSpinner" etc. and inspect that in the "find" function? Againg sorry for my ignorance but I'm a noobie in this.

Comment: You don't have to apologize. You shouldn't pass anything to the function. In javascript, `this` is a reference to *who called the function* (in your case to the button). Using the code as above should work.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle to show that it works. You can play with it a bit to understand it.

Comment: This has the same problem as my code: the first spinner works and the following spinners don't: http://jsfiddle.net/8C8c8/3/

Comment: That is because you are using `id` instead of `class`. As I explained in the last part of my answer, only one element with a similar `id` can exist. All other elements are treated as non-existent for javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/8C8c8/4/

Comment: Thank You for helping and bearing with me!